# Saving a Join Model

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been reading the cookbook for a while now and still don't get how I'm supposed to do this:

My original problem was this:
[A related Model isn't being validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519338/a-related-model-isnt-being-validated)

From RabidFire's commment:

> If you want to count the number of
>   Category models that a new Post is
>   associated with (on save), then you
>   need to do this in the beforeSave
>   function as I've mentioned. As you've
>   currently set up your models, you
>   don't need to use the multiple rule
>   anywhere. If you really, really want
>   to validate against a list of Category
>   IDs for some reason, then create a
>   join model, and validate category_id
>   with the multiple rule there.

Now, I have these models and are now validating. The problem now is that data isn't being saved in the Join Table:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'CategoryPost' => array(
            'className' => 'CategoryPost'
        )
    );
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Page' => array(
            'className' => 'Page'
        )
    );

class Category extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Category';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'CategoryPost' => array(
            'className' => 'CategoryPost'
        )
    );

class CategoryPost extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'CategoryPost';
    var $validate = array(
        'category_id' => array(
            'rule'     => array('multiple', array('in' => array(1, 2, 3, 4))),
            'required' => FALSE,
            'message'  => 'Please select one, two or three options'
        )
    );
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post'
        ),
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category'
        )
    );
```

This is the new Form:

```
<div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="main">
            <h2>Add Post</h2>
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
            <div>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Post');
            echo $this->Form->input('Post.title');
            echo $this->Form->input('CategoryPost.category_id', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
            echo $this->Form->input('Post.body', array('rows' => '3'));

            echo $this->Form->input('Page.meta_keywords');
            echo $this->Form->input('Page.meta_description');

            echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
            ?>
            </div>
    <!-- main ends -->
    </div>
```

The data I am producing from the form is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1234
            [body] => 

1234

        )

    [CategoryPost] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [Page] => Array
        (
            [meta_keywords] => 1234
            [meta_description] => 1234
            [title] => 1234
            [layout] => index
        )

)
```

UPDATE: controller action
//Controller action

```
function admin_add() {
    // pr(Debugger::trace());
    $this->set('categories', $this->Post->CategoryPost->Category->find('list'));

    if ( ! empty($this->data)) {

        $this->data['Page']['title'] = $this->data['Post']['title'];
        $this->data['Page']['layout'] = 'index';

        debug($this->data);
        if ($this->Post->saveAll($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved', 'flash_good');
            $this->redirect($this->here);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE #2:
Should I just do this manually?

The problem is that the join tables doesn't have things saved in it. Is there something I'm missing?

removed update #3

Join Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Update: #4

I will put everything about my application here in the hopes of getting to do what I want to do.

```
// Post Model
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'CategoryPost' => array(
            'className' => 'CategoryPost'
        )
    );
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Page' => array(
            'className' => 'Page'
        )
    );
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    var $virtualFields = array(
        'date_posted' => 'DATE_SUB(Post.created, INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
    );

    var $order = array('Post.modified' => 'desc');
    var $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );

    function getFeed() {
        if ($posts = $this->find('all', array('limit' => 20, 'order' => 'Post.created DESC'))) {
            return $posts;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    function getRecentPosts() {
        $conditions = array(
            'Post.created < (curdate() + interval 7 day)',
        );
        return $this->find('all', array('limit' => 8, 'conditions' => $conditions));
    }
}


// CategoryPost Model
class CategoryPost extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'CategoryPost';


    var $validate = array(
    'category_id' => array(
        'rule'     => array('multiple', array('in' => array(1, 2, 3, 4))),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'message'  => 'Please select one, two or three options'
    )
    );

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post'
        ),
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category'
        )
    );

    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}

class Page extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Page';
    var $order = array('Page.modified' => 'desc');

    var $hasOne = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post'
        ));

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Snippet' => array(
            'className' => 'Snippet'
        ));

    var $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'uris' => array(
            'slugged' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/i',
                'message' => 'This field should only contain characters, numbers, dashes and underscores'
            ),
            'uniqueUrl' => array(
                'rule' => array('uniqueUrl'),
                'message' => 'A page has already acquired this url'
            )
        ),
        'meta_keywords' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'meta_description' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'layout' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}


// Form
<div id="main">
        <h2>Add Post</h2>
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
        <div>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Post');
        echo $this->Form->input('Post.title');
        echo $this->Form->input('CategoryPost.category_id', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
        echo $this->Form->input('Post.body', array('rows' => '3'));

        echo $this->Form->input('Page.meta_keywords');
        echo $this->Form->input('Page.meta_description');

        echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
        ?>
        </div>
<!-- main ends -->
</div>


// Posts#admin_add
function admin_add() {
    $this->set('categories', $this->Post->CategoryPost->Category->find('list'));

    if ( ! empty($this->data)) {

        $this->data['Page']['title'] = $this->data['Post']['title'];
        $this->data['Page']['layout'] = 'index';


        if ($this->Post->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved', 'flash_good');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_add'));
        }

    }
}


// Table structure
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=163 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uris` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `layout` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=164 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;
```

Comment: Can you add the controller action here?

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not being saved because you're trying to save an array into a field.

```
[CategoryPost] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )
    )
```

The form of the data should look like this:

```
[CategoryPost] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 2
            )
    )
```

You could use the following code to do this:

```
// Correcting data form of CategoryPost
$categoryPosts = array();
foreach ($this->data['CategoryPost']['category_id'] as $categoryId) {
    $categoryPost = array(
        'category_id' => $categoryId
    );
    array_push($categoryPosts, $categoryPost);
}
$this->data['CategoryPost'] = $categoryPosts;
```

This code can be placed in the controller *before* the `saveAll` call. If you find that you're using this code in multiple places, you can refactor it into the model's `beforeSave`:

```
function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data['CategoryPost']['category_id']) && is_array($this->data['CategoryPost']['category_id'])) {
        ... // above code
    }
}
```

Post the schema of your join table (table name and fields) for a possibly better alternative.

---

Alright, it took me some brain racking but I finally figured it out. Your last comment kind of put everything in place. Here's the simple fix:

In your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('CategoryPost.0.category_id', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

This should cause the data to be of the following form:

```
[CategoryPost] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                    )
            )
    )
```

You **need** to have it in this form because of the **hasMany** relationship between `Post` and `CategoryPost` - *or it won't even validate.* After you make this change, the `beforeSave` function will be called. NOW make the necessary changes to beforeSave to make it work! Debugging `$this->data` will help. I leave this part to you, cause I have another **better alternative**:

1) Shift the `multiple` validation rule to the `Post` model:

```
class Post extends AppModel { 
    ...
    var $validate = array(
        'category_id' => array(
            'rule'     => array('multiple', array('in' => array(1, 2, 3, 4))),
            'required' => false,
            'message'  => 'Please select one, two or three options'
        )
    );
    ...
}
```

2) Change the view accordingly:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Post.category_id', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

3) Shift the `beforeSave` to the `Post` model:

```
function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data['Post']['category_id']) && is_array($this->data['Post']['category_id'])) {
        $categoryPosts = array();
        foreach ($this->data['Post']['category_id'] as $categoryId) {
            $categoryPost = array(
                'category_id' => $categoryId
            );
            array_push($categoryPosts, $categoryPost);
        }
        $this->data['CategoryPost'] = $categoryPosts;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This should keep things nice and smooth. Test out both alternatives and let me know if it works! :D

Comment: Yeah, I did this already and I think this one works. I might have just coded it differently. Anyway, I will look if it worked. I was on vacation.

Comment: RabidFire, I've used your code (I tried this code before)and it seems that when it saves, it reverts back to the old array before saving. I'm confused.

Comment: I even tried hardcoding a sample and it doesn't work: *$this->data['CategoryPost'][0]['category_id'] = 1;*

Comment: Try placing it in the `beforeSave` of your `CategoryPost` model.

Comment: it doesn't work. in fact, the beforeSave in the CategoryPost doesn't run at all.

Comment: Hm.... Then most probably the validation is failing. You can check this by setting `$this->Post->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'))` which will NOT save the Post data if any related model's validation fails. Try it and let us know if this happens.

Comment: it still saves the page and post but not the category_post when I wrote the `array('validate' => 'first')`

Comment: I can confirm that returning FALSE from CategoryPost::beforeSave doesn't stop saving the Post and Page.

Comment: @Thorpe - That helped me figure out what the problem was. Edited my answer to reflect the findings. :)

Comment: @Rabidfire. It now works. but the category_posts.post_id = `0`.

Comment: Rabidfire, Post.id doesn't exist yet in the beforeSave. It's one reason we might not be getting the post_id for category_posts.

Comment: @Thorpe - Sorry, there was a typo. `CategoryPost.0.category_id` -- I missed the `0`. CakePHP will automatically assign the `post_id`. Validation will only fail if you are trying to validate for a non-empty post_id (which you aren't), so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @Thorpe - Made another edit to my answer. `$this->data['CategoryPost'] = $categoryPosts;` should assign the CategoryPost correctly and save `post_id` assuming that CakePHP carries on the same data for saveAll everywhere. You need to test it out to confirm.

Comment: @RabidFire, I was following your solution. I haven't worked the first. I was working on your alternative.

Comment: @Thorpe - Yea, you'd posted 2 comments and I missed the first. I made an edit to the alternative solution in the `beforeSave`. Just assign $categoryPosts back into the data and let it return true.

Comment: RabidFire, that last one didn't save anything at all. I modified my code to fit the question and gave all information that I think would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the element for multiple choice should have name like this:

echo $this->Form->input('Category', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));

For better results create a backup copy of your view file and recreate it using the console bake script.

Comment: If you read the question, you'd see the previous question I asked. This was the original setup. I changed to my current setup to have validation.

Comment: Anyway, I tried to bake the app, but it doesn't do the validation on the Categories.